# Is it bad karma if you are waiting for someone to die?

Tags: theravada, mahayana, lay-buddhism

I was just wondering if it’s bad karma if you were just waiting for someone to die? For example, let’s say you asked your parents for permission to become a monk but they declined so you decided to wait until they leave this world before ordaining. Is it bad karma if you do this?

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on *why* you think this is even a question. Why is it that you think it a possibility that waiting for someone to die might entail accruing bad karma?

Comment: It's quite respectable that you have decided to wait for them to die so that you can follow dhamma. Some people wait for others to die so that they can accrue financial gains. I don't understand your culture, but here in the UK, when we reach 16 we can choose to do what we like regardless of what our parents think. If you're an adult I struggle to see how your parents can stop you or what motivations they might have for keeping you at home.

Comment: NO. Human die from time to time whether you wait or not.

Comment: @NeuroMax It may be a rule of the Sangha that you need your parents' permission (regardless of how old you are).

Comment: @ChrisW - yes, my comment doesn't cover all scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

**I was just wondering if it’s bad karma if you were just waiting for someone to die?**

> "Whatever, monks, a teacher ought to do out of compassion, for the
> profit of his disciples, that I have done, having compassion for you.
>
> "Here monks, are the roots of trees! Here are lonely places! Meditate
> monks. Do not be slothful, have no subsequent regrets. Thus we charge
> you."
>
> [SN 35.145](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.145.wlsh.html)

If you do not have any unwholesome intentions (greed, hatred, or delusion) tied up in doing so, no unwholesome kamma should fruit. Despite that, in many other ways unwholesome kamma will fruit (unless you are enlightened) and so instead of spending your time waiting, meditate! :)

**For example, let’s say you asked your parents for permission to become a monk but they declined so you decided to wait until they leave this world before ordaining. Is it bad karma if you do this?**

> "Do you have your parents' permission, Ratthapala, to go forth from
> the household life into homelessness?"
>
> "No, lord, I haven't."
>
> "Ratthapala, Tathagatas do not give the going-forth to anyone who
> doesn't have his parents' permission."
>
> "Lord, I will do what needs to be done so that my parents will give
> their permission for me to go forth from the household life into
> homelessness."
>
> [MN 82](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/mn/mn.082.than.html)

It is by tradition and respect that a lay person get their parents permission to ordain. I would suggest that you ask them in a very serious manner and list solid reasons for why you wish to ordain (and even show them your practice so they can understand your point of view better) and be persistent (some people take years convincing their parents!). I would recommend you read the entire sutta quoted above (you can find it by [clicking here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/mn/mn.082.than.html)). Refer to my answer in the previous question for if such an action will produce unwholesome kamma.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad karma *wishing* someone to die.

> [AN2.13:1.6](https://suttacentral.net/an2.13/en/sujato#an2.13:1.6): ‘Bad conduct of body, speech, or **mind** has a bad, painful result in both this life and the next.’

Also see MN81, where Ghaṭīkāra does not go forth because he is taking care of his parents:

> [MN81:11.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn81/en/sujato#mn81:11.3): ‘Don’t you know, dear Jotipāla, that I look after my blind old parents?’